# FabricJS: Merging two images for memory optimisation

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I need to run FabricJS/canvas at a pretty optimal level to work for my use-case in the browser.

I have cases where I have a background image and I need to draw more than 20000 polygons on it. This isn't possible, so I currently:
1) Generate a static PNG image of the polygons server side, then send it to the browser, and overlay that on the background image
2) Then as the user's mouse goes over the relevant areas, I load interactive Fabric annotations into that areas.

When a user selects an interactive polygon, move it around and drop it, I need to re-generate the static polygon image layer with the updated positions of that polygon. It takes too much memory to recreate the complete static polygon image with toDataUrl, the browser crashes.

Say I can then generate a small static image by using an additional smaller canvas. Then I need to merge it onto larger static polygon image. I've seen the fabric.clipTo, but using it many times over (e.g. up to 20 000 times), while fabric keeps a reference to it, will surely slow the browser down?

Is there any way in fabricjs to do the equivalent of ctx.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height); in a way that merges it into an image on the canvas without creating additional objects?

Here is an playground that I've built to try and find a way to merge changes onto the static polygon image below:

```js
const SPACING = 15;
const RECTANGLE_SIDE = 40;
const TOTAL_RECT_SPACE = RECTANGLE_SIDE + SPACING;
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 300;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 300;

const CANVAS_RECT = document.getElementById('c').getBoundingClientRect();

const app = async () => {

  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

  const rectangles = generateRectangles();

  await createStaticImage(canvas, rectangles);

  showAnnotationsOnHover(canvas, rectangles);

};

const generateRectangles = () => {

  let rectangles = [];

  for (let i = 0; (i + 1) * TOTAL_RECT_SPACE < CANVAS_WIDTH; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; (j+ 1) * TOTAL_RECT_SPACE < CANVAS_HEIGHT; j++) {
      let rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: i * TOTAL_RECT_SPACE,
        top: j * TOTAL_RECT_SPACE,
        fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        width: RECTANGLE_SIDE,
        height: RECTANGLE_SIDE
      });
      rectangles.push(rectangle);
    }
  };

  return rectangles;

}

const createStaticImage = (canvas, rectangles) => {

  return new Promise(resolve => {

    rectangles.forEach(rect => {
      rect.set({ stroke: 'blue' });
      canvas.add(rect);
    });
    const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    fabric.Image.fromURL(dataUrl, image => {
      image.set({
        selectable: false
      });
      canvas.add(image);
      resolve();
    });
    rectangles.forEach(rect => {
      rect.set({ stroke: 'red' });
      canvas.remove(rect);
    });

  });

}

const showAnnotationsOnHover = (canvas, rectangles) => {

  let showAnnotations = false;

  canvas.on('mouse:over', () => {
    if (!showAnnotations) {
      showAnnotations = true;
      rectangles.forEach(rect => {
        canvas.add(rect);
      })
    }
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:out', () => {
    if (showAnnotations) {
      showAnnotations = false;
      rectangles.forEach(rect => {
        canvas.remove(rect);
      });
    }
  });

}

app();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color: lightblue; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box; ; vertical-align: top">
      <p> Hovering on the canvas shows Fabric Annotations. Otherwise it's a static image </p>
      <p> When a rectangle is moved, that change should be flattened down to the static image of the rectangles below. </p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 300px; vertical-align: top">
      <canvas id="c" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is unclear why a server should be faster than an hardware accelerate canvas to draw an image with many polygons. Or if that crash a browser, why many concurrent users should not crash a server. Did you try an offscreen canvas or to figure out why fabricjs is taking so much memory and try to avoid it?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi To create a high-enough quality image from the polygons, the canvas is about 4000x5000 pixels big. Calling toDataUrl on that takes about 40 seconds on Chrome and breaks transparency in the PNG for some reason. Doing it on the server just allows me to generate the static image beforehand, saving the user 40 seconds of waiting on page load. So ideally I want to generate the large image beforehand and then just merge smaller image changes onto the image while the user is working.